# How to change list item marker when it is active

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am using bootstrap 5.0

I want to change the color of the list marker when the nav-link is .active

See my code below. Nothing seems to work

```css
nav ul li::marker{
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 600;
    content: "\2716";
  }

.nav-link.active {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
```

```html
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-light d-none d-md-flex flex-md-column align-items-beginning">
                  <ul>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link active" href="#item1">Item 1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#item2">Item 2</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#item3">Item 3</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#item4">Item 4</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </nav>
```

Comment: Post your complete code. Where is "active" added in your HTML? If you can replicate the demo, then you can get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks, @m4n0 I have added in the active class. In the same place where it gets added on the browser

Comment: This is not possible via CSS until we see this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has but can be done via JS.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery you can change marker color

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".nav-link.active").parents('li').css("color", "red");
});
```

```css
nav ul li::marker{
    font-weight: 600;
    content: "\2716";
  }

.nav-link.active {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
```

```html
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-light d-none d-md-flex flex-md-column align-items-beginning">
                  <ul>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link active" href="#item1">Item 1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#item2">Item 2</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#item3">Item 3</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#item4">Item 4</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, @satish-modha for your response.
I am not very familiar with Js and jQuery, but I <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> is causing a conflict with the theme (WordPress) I am using, so it isn't working as in the snippet.

Is it possible to this with vanilla JS?

I tried this 

function liColor(){
  getElementByClassName(".nav-link.active").elementParent.color = "red";
 }
 
 window.onload=liColor();

but that didn't work